Moving all files from sub-subfolders to the main subfolder
Using Windows, or using a 3rd party free program.
Is there a way to bulk move all the contents of subfolders up a level while deleting the sub folder?
In other words, a way to get rid of selected subfolders while moving their contents one level
I'd like to go from:
Main Folder
Subfolder1
Subfolder1

File1
File2

Subfolder2
Subfolder2

File1
File2

To:
Main Folder
Subfolder1
File1
File2

Subfolder2
File1
File2

In a single process.

Im trying to understand what your file tree looks like. It would help if you googled what a file tree looks like when printed in a console, then use that type of formatting to draw the file tree you are starting with, and another file tree to show the tree you desire. If you do that I can probably give you a solution using the Win Cmd Prompt or PwrSh.
